# LinearSolve with 4 variables and 3 equations

Tags: equation-solving

Is it possible to find a solution or at least run LinearSolve when there are 4 variables and 3 equations.

For example:

a + b -3c + 4d = 4;
2a + 5b -6c +2d = 15;
3a -4b + 5c -3d = 10.

Comment: With 3 equations and 4 variables you can only hope  3 variables as functions of the 4'th variable. Solve will do the job

Comment: This query now not related to Mathematica but linear algebra. When it is said '3 variables as functions of the 4th variable', does it mean 3 can be any of a,b,c,d and 'function of the 4th variable' the remaining one.

Comment: Usually, any three of {a,b,c,d} can be functions of the 4th variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
eq = {a + b - 3 c + 4 d == 4, 2 a + 5 b - 6 c + 2 d == 15, 
   3 a - 4 b + 5 c - 3 d == 10};
Solve[eq, {a, b, c}]
Solve[eq, {a, b, d}]
Solve[eq, {a, c, d}]
Solve[eq, {b, c, d}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it clarified.

Comment: I find it strange if the solution set (using LinearSolve) can be a set of four numbers. For instance {1,2,3,0}. I am not reproducing the actual problem since it is part of an exercise that Wolfram prohibits sharing. I can share on message though.

Answer (score 6):

Your system of equations can be written in matrix form:

```
M = {{1, 1, -3, 4},
     {2, 5, -6, 2},
     {3, -4, 5, -3}};
q = {4, 15, 10};

Thread[M . {a, b, c, d} == q]
(*    {a + b - 3 c + 4 d == 4,
       2 a + 5 b - 6 c + 2 d == 15,
       3 a - 4 b + 5 c - 3 d == 10}    *)
```

As [@DanielHuber](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/46318/daniel-huber) points out, there are infinitely many solutions $x=\{a,b,c,d\}$. The one with smallest norm can be found through the [Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PseudoInverse.html) of `M`:

```
x0 = PseudoInverse[M] . q
(*    {2781/610, 1817/2745, -3883/5490, -2294/2745}    *)
```

All other solutions differ from `x0` by any vector from the [nullspace](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NullSpace.html) of `M`: (here the nullspace only contains one vector)

```
n = NullSpace[M]
(*    {{3, 28, 29, 14}}    *)

x[t_] = x0 + {t} . n
(*    {2781/610 + 3 t, 
       1817/2745 + 28 t,
       -3883/5490 + 29 t,
       -2294/2745 + 14 t}    *)
```

Check:

```
M . x[t] == q // Expand
(*    True    *)
```

Comment: Alternatively `x0 = LeastSquares[M, q]`

Comment: So LinearSolve[A,b] in case of 3 equations and 4 variables with give output of the one with the smallest norm?

Comment: Yes, just like the Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse.